# How to move a thread or process to another computer

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I am trying to serialize a thread (or Process) to a file and execute the thread on a different machine at some other time.

Actually what I have is something like this:

```
 for (BigInteger i = 0; i < ABigIntegerVariable; i++)
    {
        // My Calculation 
    }
```

I want to suspend the computation and save its state, and resume it later with the saved state, possibly on a different machine.

**note**: I can't save data at the program closing cuz it contains object and It seems that it is note true to save an object

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you can't save your objects on disk ? Did you have a look at the binary serialization : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx There is some limitations when serializing to xml/SOAP/JSON, but i never had any problems saving complex objects in binary format.

Comment: "Objects" aren't transfered to other computers, much less whole threads or processes. You would have to start a program at another computer, then make both communicate and have the second pick off where the first left.

Comment: Why can't you serialize the `object`, not `Thread`?

Comment: @Alejandro - objects maybe not but serialized data can be transferred even on floppy disc assuming that destination process will know what to do with those data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just save your current loop iterator value and whatever calculation state is at the time you want to "move" it? It depends of course what exactly is happening inside that loop but maybe even crude serialization after each iteration would be enough for you to start at new location?

Of course your loop would have to start from saved data not from i = 0 but as I said, you didn't share any details about what is going on in //My Calculation so either put more details in question or try to figure it out on your own.

Also, as per comment from Sidewinder94, there's no problem with serialization of objects unless you are doing it wrong.

One additional thought: are those calculations dependent on your loop iterator or result of previous loop(s)? Because if not you could just split them into multiple threads/tasks and take advantage of parallel calculations.